# Linking WPF project to Windows Azure Database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, visual-studio, azure

I'm relatively new to Windows Azure. Up until now my C# WPF project (Visual Studio 2012) has been accessing a local DB. Having recently set up a Windows Azure account I want to migrate the local DB to Azure.

I have created a SQL Database on Azure.

I am working on adding the C# code in order to pass the data from the local application to the cloud. In order to test this functionality I have added a random user who I want to insert into the Azure DB.

Here is what I have so far:

In App.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="STAREntites"
        connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net;
                     Database=xxxxx;
                     Uid=xxxxx.database.windows.net;
                     Pwd=xxxxx;
                     Encrypt=Yes;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have a 'Model' folder containing `PersonRepository.cs`:

```
public class PersonEntity : TableEntity
{
    public PersonEntity()
    {
    }
    public PersonEntity(int id, string name, double sal)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Salary = sal;
        PartitionKey = id.ToString();
        RowKey = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

}

Within my registration page I also have the following code to send the data to the Azure DB:

```
private void RegisterUser()
    {
             string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["STAREntites"].ConnectionString;                           
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connStr);
            CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference("PersonTable");
            table.CreateIfNotExists();
            var emp = new PersonTable
            {
                FirstName = "Cor",
                LastName = "Mky",
                EmailAddress = "cm@email.com",
                Password = "password",
            };

            TableOperation insertOp = TableOperation.Insert(emp);
            table.Execute(insertOp);

    }
```

At the moment I can see via Server Explorer that the test user added from the `RegisterUser` method is inserted into the person table within Windows Azure Storage. However when I check the Azure SQL DB the entity is not present.

Can anyone help as to why the entity is not being sent to Azure?

I have checked my ports are listening and that SQL server is running. I am getting no errors in Visual Studio.

Comment: Your UID looks strange. Should be "uuuuu@xxxxx".

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about the types of storage. `CloudStorageAccount` is used for Azure Storage: Tables, Blobs and Queues, not for Windows Azure SQL Database.

I'm not quite sure how `CloudStorageAccount.Parse` isn't throwing an error if you're passing it what looks like a SQL Server connection string.

If you want to use Entity Framework with a Windows Azure SQL Database, just use regular `DbContext` code and provide the ADO.NET connection string to the WASD, which would look like what you have except that the Uid should be `Uid=uuuuu@xxxxx`.

If you want to use Table Storage, then you should be looking in Table Storage to see your inserted entity using something like [Zudio](https://zud.io/).

[Information on the available Azure storage options](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/data-management/).